# Manually typing commands into console works but not in the program

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm having a problem where I can do every single function in a command line version of lua however, when I run the program it won't throw any errors it just ends.I'm not sure how to diagnose this but I have tried getting an error to be thrown a couple times for different things and it will error and print the error.

```
power = peripheral.wrap("bottom")
mon = peripheral.wrap("top")

x,y = mon.getSize()

clearTerm = function()
  term.clear()
  term.setCursorPos(1,1)
end

clearBoth = function()
  clearMon()
  clearTerm()
end

intLen = function(bar)
  tab = tostring(bar)
  tab = string.len(tab)
  return tab
end

checkPower = function()
  total = power.getMaxEnergyStored()
  local til = intLen(total)
  local yy = math.floor(y/2)
  local tol = math.floor(x-til)
  mon.setCursorPos(yy+0,tol/2)
  for z=1,til do mon.write("-") end
  mon.setCursorPos(yy-1,tol/2)
  mon.write(total)
  while true do
    current = power.getEnergyStored()
    local cil = intLen(current)
    local col = math.floor(x-cil)
    mon.setCursorPos(yy+1,col/2)
    mon.write(current)
    sleep(1)
  end
end
```

I'll leave a link to the pastebin of the full program [here](http://pastebin.com/CpGDn5B5) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can add some outputs to your code. Just add stuff like

```
print "1" -- debug output
...
print "2" -- debug output
...
-- don't forget to remove these after you're done debugging!
```

to your code and see how many of them you see when running the program, this way you can narrow down when exactly the program crashes.

Also, I cannot find where the function clearMon() is defined, might that be source the problem, or is it defined elsewhere?

Comment: You can also do this to remove print statements: `debug = false; print = debug and print or function() end`

Comment: @DavisDude Nice idea, but I would call the "new" print functrion differently. You could just type debug_print = print and later change that to debug_print = function() end.
EDIT: I still suggest to remove that after you're done debugging to keep the code clean and a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Yeah, but if you're lazy you can always leave them :P

Comment: I did figure out what was wrong with the code, I had the x and y backwards. So it was printing off the screen and throwing an error but immediately crashing because the cursor was also off the screen. @DarkWiiPlayer I also tried that but it was crashing so early that it wouldn't print past the first one. Also clearMon() was defined somewhere else in the code but for debugging purposes I removed that function from my code, I just forgot to take it off on here.